# Как подключить тень?

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, подскажите как устранить вот эту проблему:

У меня стоит вот такой код для тени

```
.shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #ADADAD;   /* Firefox до версии 4.0 */ 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #ADADAD;  /* Safari и Chrome */ 
   /* Костыли для IE до версии 9 */ 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(offX=5, offY=5, color=#ADADAD);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.shadow(direction=120, color=#ADADAD, strength=10);
  box-shadow: 5 5 10px #ADADAD;  /* для всех остальных, которые поддерживают CSS3 */ 
}
```

Но opera не отображает тень, что надо еще дописать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Опера поддерживает свойство box-shadow начиная с версии 10.50

Так что для версий ниже стандартными средствами скорее всего никак. Только с помощью js или картинками. Но, ориентироваться на оперу ниже 10.50, это почти как и писать под ИЕ6 - неблагодарное и ненужное занятие: [пруфлинк](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_opera.asp), [2](http://trends.openstat.ru/global-statistic-browsers/#level=3&attr=1%252C2%252C3).

Comment: Нет ну была же опера у которой тени работали только через `-o-box-shadow`, сам даже писал такое :)

А вообще уже все адекватные браузеры поддерживают просто `box-shadow`( естественно IE ятадекватным не считаю ^^ )

Comment: +1 за IE, помню когда написание костылей под ИЕ6 занимало больше времени, чем весь сайт целиком.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, как-то так

```
 -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #ADADAD;
```

Comment: пасиба, но чето не отображает, видимо отключено что-то